# How to Programmatically load a SPList from an Generic List...?

Tags: development, visual-studio

After running the program... I check my site and only see city5.  I also have a console app that undoes all below.  The `foreach` loop only works for the last item.  Tying to load all 5 cities...

```
static void Main()
{
    List<string> cities = new List<string>();
    cities.Add("city1");
    cities.Add("city2");
    cities.Add("city3");
    cities.Add("city4");
    cities.Add("city5");

    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://splab04/"))
    {
        using (SPWeb parentWeb = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            //Creating main Site/web
            Console.WriteLine("Creating Web...");
            SPWeb newWeb = parentWeb.Webs.Add("ABCHospital");
            Console.WriteLine("Web: ABCHospital has been created...");

            //Creating subweb/SubSite HR
            Console.WriteLine("Creating SubWeb HR");
            SPWeb newSubWeb = newWeb.Webs.Add("HR");
            Console.WriteLine("SubWeb: HR Created");

            //Creating Contact List
            if (newWeb.Lists.TryGetList("ContactList") == null)
            {
                SPListCollection lists = newWeb.Lists;
                SPListTemplateType listTemplateType = SPListTemplateType.Contacts;

                lists.Add("ContactList", "List created via VS2K10", listTemplateType);
                Console.WriteLine("List Created");

                //Create List columne name-Header
                Console.WriteLine("Adding Columne to List");
                SPList lst = newWeb.Lists["ContactList"];
                SPFieldText fldCities = (SPFieldText)lst.Fields.CreateNewField(SPFieldType.Text.ToString(), "Cities");                        
                lst.Fields.Add(fldCities);                        
                lst.Update();
                Console.WriteLine("List Columne Created...");

                Console.WriteLine("Loading Contact list with Cities...");
                SPListItem newData = lst.Items.Add();                        
                foreach (string city in cities)
                {
                    //newData["RowID"] = lst.ID;
                    newData["Cities"] = city.ToString();
                    newData.Update();
                    Console.WriteLine("City Added to Contacts List: " + city.ToString());                            
                }                        
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List Exists.");
            }                    

            //Creating Library
            SPWeb parentWeb1 = site.AllWebs["HenryFordHospital"];
            parentWeb1.Lists.Add("Policies", "This was created Programatically", SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
            Console.WriteLine("Document Library Policies has been created...");

            //Loading Document Library
            Console.WriteLine("Loading Document Libray");

            Console.WriteLine("Document Libray loaded...");
            Console.ReadLine();                    
        }                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (string city in cities)
{
    SPListItem newData = lst.Items.Add();
    //newData["RowID"] = lst.ID;
    newData["Cities"] = city.ToString();
    newData.Update();
    Console.WriteLine("City Added to Contacts List: " + city.ToString());
}
```

This way you are actually creating a new item for each iteration of the loop. Otherwise, you are creating one new item, and repeatedly updating the field "Cities" with each iteration. IE: You're saving it as "city1", then overwriting that with, "city2", city3", "city4", and finally "city5". This is why it appears that only the last iteration is being added.

Comment: Gezzzz how simple was that... worked like a charm...

Comment: Sometimes you just need another set of eyes :)